# Break up locales/en.json into multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I want to break up my localization json files into blocks each representing an area of the page in sailsjs. So instead of loading just en.json it would load all files for locale en like en.block1.json and en.block2.json when I set locale to 'en'.

Is there any way of doing this? I have searched online and can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sails uses [`i18n`](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node)[(npm)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n) module for i18n support.

Looking into this module's code, it seems that it expects a single file ([code](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node/blob/master/i18n.js#L1084)) in JSON format for a locale.

One way to solve your use case will be to **have a Grunt task** which reads `en.*.json` files and **merges them** into a `en.json` file for `i18n` module. Run this grunt task while lifting your app.